# Experience Manager Finish Editing issue

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, multimedia

The components which are getting published through Finish Editing has multimedia comp links.

Issue #1 - I am not sure why publishing is happening dynamically for some components and not all as I can see the small blue symbol on the published component. Due to this it's appending the tcmid of the multimedia comp to the images title due to dynamic publishing .

Issue #2 - Since the images now has the tcmid it's not rendering on the page as the in the code it's fetched normally.

Please suggest.

Comment: The linked images aren't "published" in a typical way (not resolved) in this case. They're _implicitly published_, by template code (i.e. `addBinary()` mentioned below). See Frank van Puffelen's [Binary Event Tracker article](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/binaryeventtracker.aspx)for the difference. In terms of the appended ID, that sounds like [behavior from before R5.3](http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx), I'm not sure but could it be a really old template in the system?

Comment: I think we need more details, like actual html or even a list of the TBBs in the CT... It is not clear yet to me whether (or for that matter when) the tcmid is appended to the file name...

Answer (score 1):

Components only get dynamically published if you have a dyncamic Component Template associated to the Schema they are based on.

Check your publishing queue to see what is being sent to be published. Regarding the `TCM URI` being appended to the end of the multimedia filename has to do with the the way binaries are published. So, check your Templates and check what Template Building Blocks are used to publish binaries.

First thing you need to do is to identify what CT is rendering your Multimedia Component ( tag). Doing a where used in the Schemas (both the "main" and the "multimedia" component are based on) will show you the Templates rendering such content types. Remember to do this where used at the "web" level.

Comment: We can see the comps in the pub queue that are getting changed through site-edit and are publishing dynamically even though they are not attached to any DCT. These comps have multimedia links inside which are also getting published dynamically through a dynamic CT which we have  located in tridion. Now I am not getting one thing is why at the first place the main comp is getting published dynamically through odata. Is it the normal XPM behaviour ? These are image filenames with tcm appended. AL_callout_history_125x125_tcm55-11984

Comment: What you are seeing there is Dynamic Linking, if you publish something which is linked from somewhere (like a multimedia component linked from a regular component). It will trigger the publishing of the referencing component. And yes, that's the regular Session Preview behaviour. I am going to stick to my original answer, in order for somethign to get published, there's a template associated to it.

Comment: Yes i understand, but the component which is edited is not in any other component, it's directly added in the page with an  embedded CT. Now since it's the default behaviour of XPM to publish dynamically then it should fail as there is no DCT for this component. Let's leave the multimedia issue for now and understand the publishing of components by odata.

Comment: Session preview will re-publish the edited item through oData to the "Wrapper" database. The configuration used for that publishing, it is, the bindings, is the same as for regular publishing. Now, you say "it is directly added to the page with an embedded CT". Do you mean it is a regular CP in the page that contains a Component Link in it or is it a CP that Contains another Embedded Component Presentation? Either way the output of your CPs should be the same regardless normal-publish or odata-publish occurs. Can you share the page source code before and after?

Comment: Yes Jaime, you are right, there were few DCT's which had the same schema used by the component in their linked schema. Now the image has no tcmid appended which makes them to render correctly. So my original question still holds now that why the multimedia components if published through DCT's have the tcmid appended. The same multimedia component if published with Page has no tcmid in it's title though both of them use the same Default Finish action. If it's the AddBinary in DFA adding the tcmid's then why it's not adding when the same mm comp is published through the page.

Comment: I think "link propagation" would be a better term for items publishing due to something linking to them rather than Dynamic Linking. But in this case, the OP is not publishing the image directly.

Comment: I think we need more details, like actual html or even a list of the TBBs in the CT... It is not clear yet to me whether (or for that matter when) the tcmid is appended to the file name...